# How can I quote iframe's javascript variable in parent's window

Tags: javascript, variables, iframe, quote

In A.html I open an iframe with B.html in it.

in B.html,I write js:

```
<script type="javascript">
    var b=0;

   function test(){
       alert(b);
       return b;
   }
</script>
```

so in A.html I want quote the variable b in B.html
I write this:

```
<script type="javascript">
    var a;

    a=window.frames[0].b;
    alert(a);
</script>
```

but the resault is "undefined";
however,I quote the function test in A.html

```
<script type="javascript">
    var a;

    a=window.frames[0]. test();
    alert(a);
</script>
```

both the variable a and b could alert correctly

so why the second quote method could not work?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

Which browser do you use?
Are you sure that the document inside the frame is already loaded when you access the property?